# Fast way to multiple 3D tensors of shape (1, 1, 256) and (10, 1, 256) in PyTorch and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to adapt the seq2seq model for my own task, https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/blob/master/seq2seq-translation/seq2seq-translation.ipynb

I have two tensors at the decoder stage

```
rnn_output: (1, 1, 256)       # time_step x batch_size x hidden_dimension
encoder_inputs: (10, 1, 256)  # seq_len   x batch_size x hidden_dimension
```

They should be multipied to get attention score (before softmax) of shape

```
attn_score: (10, 1, 1)
```

What's the best way to do so? The notebook seems to use a for loop, is there are better via a matrix multiplication kind of operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example using [`torch.bmm()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.bmm):

```python
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np

seq_len = 10
rnn_output = torch.rand((1, 1, 256))
encoder_outputs = torch.rand((seq_len, 1, 256))

# As computed in the tutorial:
attn_score = Variable(torch.zeros(seq_len))
for i in range(seq_len):
    attn_score[i] = rnn_output.squeeze().dot(encoder_outputs[i].squeeze())
    # note: the code would fail without the "squeeze()". I would assume the tensors in
    # the tutorial are actually (,256) and (10, 256)

# Alternative using batched matrix multiplication (bmm) with some data reformatting first:
attn_score_v2 = torch.bmm(rnn_output.expand(seq_len, 1, 256),
                          encoder_outputs.view(seq_len, 256, 1)).squeeze()

# ... Interestingly though, there are some numerical discrepancies between the 2 methods:
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(attn_score.data.numpy(), 
                                     attn_score_v2.data.numpy(), decimal=5)
# AssertionError: 
# Arrays are not almost equal to 5 decimals
# 
# (mismatch 30.0%)
#  x: array([60.32436, 69.04288, 72.04784, 70.19503, 71.75543, 67.45459,
#        63.01708, 71.70189, 63.07552, 67.48799], dtype=float32)
#  y: array([60.32434, 69.04287, 72.0478 , 70.19504, 71.7554 , 67.4546 ,
#        63.01709, 71.7019 , 63.07553, 67.488  ], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Is `.expand` fast, seems an awful lot of copying if `seq_len` is large?

Comment: Unlike [`torch.repeat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat), [`torch.expand()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) just creates a view, without copying any data.

Comment: I benchmarked the two answers: @Aldream's `torch.bmm` approach: **20.3 µs ± 1.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)** vs @filippo's `einsum` approach: **57.3 µs ± 3.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)**

Comment: The for loop approach is the slowest: **75.2 µs ± 2.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)**

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking, interesting to see the comparison!

Comment: @zyxue makes sense, einsum support seems pretty young.. wondering though how much overhead is given by  trying to keep the desired `(10,1,1)` shape. Removing `->abc` should make it slightly faster

Answer (score 3):

No experience with `pytorch`, but could something like this work?

```
torch.einsum('ijk,abk->abc', (rnn_output, encoder_inputs))
```

It takes the dot product over last axis and adds a couple of empty axes back.

Something similar can be achieved with pure numpy (`pytorch 0.4` doesn't have the `...` notation yet)

```
np.einsum('...ik,...jk', rnn_output.numpy(), encoder_inputs.numpy())
```

Or with `np.tensordot`

```
np.tensordot(rnn_output.numpy(), encoder_inputs.numpy(), axes=[2,2])
```

But here you will get output shape: `(1, 1, 10, 1)`

Which you could fix by squeezing and re-expanding (*almost sure there must be some cleaner way to do this*)

```
 np.tensordot(rnn_output.numpy(), encoder_inputs.numpy(), axes=[2,2]).squeeze()[..., None, None]
```

Comment: Yes, `einsum` would be a straightforward solution, but I don't think it is released in Pytorch yet (?), though it may be soon cf. [github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1889).

Comment: @Aldream as far as I can see there is basic support in `pytorch 0.4` (latest stable version) and more extensive support (like `...` notation) is coming in the next release

Comment: @Aldream see e.g. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=einsum#torch.einsum the *batch multiplication* example and here https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=einsum#torch.einsum a preview of that's coming in git master

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that feature. Nice! Thanks for sharing :)